# How can I add notification timer like whatsapp call notification?

Tags: android, timer, notifications, call

I have a notification builder. I want to add notification timer like whatsapp call notification. So if I call updateNotifTime function, is not working.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, callChannelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.call_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

public void updateNotifTime() {
    this.callingElapsedRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    elapsedTime += 1000;

                    String timer = DateUtils.calculateTime(elapsedTime);

                    builder.setWhen(elapsedTime);

                    callingElapsedHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            };

callingElapsedHandler.postDelayed(callingElapsedRunnable, 1000);
    }
```

[image: whatsapp notification timer]
[image: my app notification]

Comment: Try using: .setUsesChronometer(true) **TIP**: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setUsesChronometer(boolean)

Comment: I tried this but still not working :(

Comment: oh, can you try and use in parallel: setChronometerCountDown(boolean)

Comment: setChronometerCountDown(boolean) is not defined

Comment: `.setChronometerCountDown(true)`

Comment: yeap it is not working ,it is covered by red line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158833/discussion-between-manmeetp-and-questioner).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added custom layout for <5.0 sdk versions:

**< 5.0**

```
public void startChronometer(String elapsedTime) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && builder != null) {
            RemoteViews mContentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.call_notification);
            //timerTxt
            TextView timerTxt = new TextView(context);
            timerTxt.setId(R.id.timerTxt);

            //callTypeTxt
            TextView callTypeTxt = new TextView(context);
            callTypeTxt.setId(R.id.callType);

            //calleeNameTxt
            TextView calleeNameTxt = new TextView(context);
            calleeNameTxt.setId(R.id.calleeName);

            mContentView.setTextViewText(timerTxt.getId(), elapsedTime);
            mContentView.setTextViewText(callTypeTxt.getId(), context.getString(R.string.call_in_progress));

            builder.setCustomBigContentView(mContentView);
            notificationManager.notify(CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        }
    }
```

**other versions**

```
builder.setUsesChronometer(true);
```

**@Kishore Jethava Question:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("tappedTime", System.currentTimeMillis());

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: I have used this code but still, I'm getting `bad notification posted`

Comment: Do you want notification timer?

Comment: Yes, same as whats app call.

Comment: thanks, It's working now. can I get that time when user tap on that notification?

Comment: yeap you can listen that tapped notification.

Comment: Yes, I know we can use pending intent, but How can I get that running time in the activity?

Comment: please try that

Answer (score 2):

```
private void sendNotification(String from, String messageText) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(from)
            .setContentText(messageText)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a very simple method.
My initial notification

```
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CALL_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentText("Incoming Voice Call")
            .setContentTitle(getDoctor().name)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_call_received_24)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setUsesChronometer(true)
            .setFullScreenIntent(voicePendingIntent, true);
    startForeground(1, notification.build());
```

store the timestamp when service started

```
    public void startTimer() {
    if (!isTimerRunning) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        isTimerRunning = true;
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "startTimer request for an already running timer");
    }
}
```

every time you call elapsedTime(),(usually in the activity to get time), the notification gets updated.

```
    public long elapsedTime() {
    if (isTimerRunning()) {
        durationMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        notification.setWhen(startTime);
        notification.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
        return (durationMillis);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```